# Reserving space in layout

Tags: android, layout

I would like to reserve space at the bottom of a layout for a row of buttons, and give the rest over to my main view (e.g. a WebView).

I know about LinearLayout using a height of 0dp and a weight ... but that gives a proportional division, e.g. 80% for webview and 20% for buttons (wrapping the buttons in a RelativeLayout and giving it the weight of 20).

On different devices, though, 20% may be overkill for the row of buttons.  I need to reserve a specific amount of space for the buttons -- say, 48dp -- and then give the rest of the layout to the WebView.

How is this accomplished?

Comment: The LinearLayout contains both the WebView and the RelativeLayout which in turn contains the buttons.  The LinearLayout fills the screen vertically, containing both other elements.  If the webview is set to fill_parent (it's parent being the LinearLayout), then the buttons are not shown.

Answer (score -1):

You can set `weight` with `height="0dp` for one view and set only `height` for another - that way the view with `weight` will fill remaining space.

Comment: Thank you.  I swear I tried that before asking here and it didn't wor ... but now it is, so I must have done something differently the first time.